# 800ac350 missing parameter: OLEDB provider

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, oracle11g, oledb, oledbconnection

I am debugging an application written in Classic ASP. The app connects to Oracle db in cloud but I get this error :

```
Code: 800ac350

Description : missing parameter OLEDB provider.
```

Does anyone has any idea why I am getting this error.

I am using x64 bit drivers for Oracle connectivity and the db is Oracle11g.

Rohit

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=bwqa09;User Id=COMPMAST;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: Yes, that looks OK.  I'd experiment with `Provider=MSDAORA` (ie lose the .1).  Also, have you enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool.  It's often a good idea to disable this if you're using 64 bit drivers/components

Comment: Yes, that is enabled.

Comment: In which case my guess is that IIS is looking for a 32 bit version of the driver and not finding it

Comment: Should I disable that first then ?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting

Comment: ok, Will give it a try